# Do I need to remove hardhat console.log from Solidity contract before deploying?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hardhat supports an implementation of `console.log` in Solidity programs.

Do I need to remove instances of console.log in my code before deploying the contract? Will it waste gas if actually deployed to production, or is it omitted during deploy?

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#console-log

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* to remove them because `console.log` calls are no-ops* in mainnet. But they consume a bit of gas, so it's a good idea to do it anyway.

<sub>*: Kind of. You can actually inspect them with [Tenderly](https://tenderly.co/).</sub>